# Putting two SQL statements together

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert, union

I am new at SQL and I am just trying to add two SQL statements together which are below. The first table is a basic make table pulling in only fields I need and then the second table is pulling the same information but appending it to the first table I made in Step 1 . I have been doing some research and what I think I need to do is a union query but I am not sure how to go about that any help please?

```
/*first step*/
/*Select 
[NPI],
[Last Name],
[First Name],
[Middle Name],
Suffix,
Gender,
[Spoken Languages]
Into [Provider Table]
From sylvia.dbo.UNIQUEACN*/

/*Second step appending PCCN Providers*/
Insert into [sylvia].dbo.[provider Table] ( NPI, [Last Name], [First Name], [Middle Name], Suffix, Gender, [spoken languages] ) 
Select sylvia.dbo.[PCCNProviders].NPI, sylvia.dbo.PCCNProviders.[Last Name],sylvia.dbo.PCCNProviders.[First Name], sylvia.dbo.PCCNProviders.[Middle Name], sylvia.dbo.PCCNProviders.suffix, sylvia.dbo.PCCNProviders.gender, sylvia.dbo.PCCNProviders.[Spoken Languages]
From sylvia.dbo.[PCCNproviders];
```

Comment: Please format your code better.

Answer (score 0):

Because your 2 tables have the same number and order of columns, you can simply execute the below query. Use `UNION ALL` if you want to keep duplicated values from both tables or just `UNION` if you want all duplicated values to be removed.

```
SELECT *
-- INTO [Combined_table] 
FROM sylvia.dbo.UNIQUEACN
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM  sylvia.dbo.[PCCNproviders]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I did just that I did a union query and its way cleaner then what I was doing .. Thanks again!! Ive been doing SQL for a week and as you can tell its a struggle but getting there

```
Select 
a.[NPI],
a.[Last Name],
a.[First Name],
a.[Middle Name],
a.Suffix,
a.Gender,
a.[Spoken Languages]
Into [Provider test]
From sylvia.dbo.UNIQUEACN a
Union
Select
b.[NPI],
b.[Last Name],
b.[First Name],
b.[Middle Name],
b.Suffix,
b.Gender,
b.[Spoken Languages]
From sylvia.dbo.[PCCNproviders] b
```